# HUD not working on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: hud

When I press Alt I can see the search field, but when I start to type I get no results. This issue is present on every application (e.g. Nautilus, Gimp, Firefox). How can I solve it?

Comment: Have you tried typing in another language?